# Distributive property of Hadarmad product wrt Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory

I have a matrix multiplication $\mathbf{B} \cdot \Omega, \quad$ where $\mathbf{B}$ is $n \times m$, with $n>m, \quad$ and $\Omega$ is a vertical vector $m \times 1$, with $m>1$.

The components of $\Omega$ are defined in this way:
$$
\omega_i = k_i + x_i p_i
$$
Now I wish to separate the various components parts (because $k_i$ are constant, $p_i$ are variable but known, and $x_i$ are variable and unknown). My goal is to "find" the $x_i$ components, and all other values are known.

If I call $\mathrm{K}, \mathrm{X}, \mathrm{P}$ the vertical vectors each containing the respective components, and $\mathbf{M}_P$ the diagonal matrix having the $p_i$ component on the diagonal, such that:
$$
\Omega = \mathrm{K} + (\mathrm{X} \circ \mathrm{P})  \\
= \mathrm{K} + \mathbf{M}_P \cdot \mathrm{X}
$$
where $\mathrm{A} \circ \mathrm{B}$ is the element-wise Hadarmad product, 
is it possible to have the following equivalence (or something similar)?
$$
\mathbf{B} \cdot \Omega = \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{K} + \mathbf{B}_1\cdot\mathrm{X} + \mathbf{B}_2\cdot\mathrm{P}
$$
And if the answer is yes, which are the $\mathbf{B}_1$ and $\mathbf{B}_2$ matrices? 
Is it possible to have either $\mathbf{B}_1 = \mathbf{B}$ or $\mathbf{B}_2 = \mathbf{B}$ so that I can put $\mathbf{B}_u = f(\mathbf{X})$ ? ($\mathbf{B}_u$ is the unknown matrix, so for example if $\mathbf{B}_2 = \mathbf{B}$ then $\mathbf{B}_1 \equiv \mathbf{B}_u$)

I hope the problem is well-posed and my english (and math :D ) is understandable.

Thanks everyone for the help

Eventine

Comment: Wouldn't $B_1 = B \cdot M_P$ and $B_2 = 0$ work?

Comment: Yes, but my goal is to separate the $p_i$ components from $x_i$ ones. This is why I was asking about the distributive property of Hadarmad product wrt Matrix multiplication.

Comment: But the resulting $B_1$ and $B_2$ would be a function of $p$ and $x$ respectively, so you don't really have separated them from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
$Let's use lowercase letters to denote vectors and reserve uppercase letters for matrix variables. Then you can write your equation as
$$w = k + p\odot x$$ where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Define the diagonal matrix
$$P=\Diag{p} \quad\implies\quad Px = p\odot x$$
Now you can solve for the unknown vector directly
$$\eqalign{
Px &= (w-k) \qquad\implies\quad x = P^{-1}(w-k) \\
}$$
Multiply the solution vector by $B_1$
$$\eqalign{
&B_1x = B_1P^{-1}w - B_1P^{-1}k \\
&B_1P^{-1}w = B_1P^{-1}k + B_1x \\
&Bw = Bk + BPx + 0p \qquad\implies\quad B=B_1P^{-1} \\
}$$
(This solution was pointed out in the comments to your post)

---

Unfortunately, there is no distributive rule for Hadamard-Matrix products, in general.

However, there **is** a specialized rule for a pair of dense matrices $(A,B)$ and a pair of diagonal matrices $(X,Y)$
$$\eqalign{
\LR{A\odot B}\LR{X\odot Y} &= \LR{AX}\odot\LR{BY} \\
\LR{X\odot Y}\LR{A\odot B} &= \LR{XA}\odot\LR{YB} \\
}$$
And there is a rule for dense matrices
and the cartesian basis vectors $\{e_k\}$
$$\eqalign{
\LR{A\odot B}e_k &= \LR{Ae_k}\odot\LR{Be_k} \\
e_k^T\LR{A\odot B} &= \LR{e_k^TA}\odot\LR{e_k^TB} \\
}$$
And there are several rules for when **all** of the variables are vectors
$$\eqalign{
\LR{a\odot b}\LR{x\odot y}^T
 &= \LR{ax^T}\odot\LR{by^T}
  = \LR{ay^T}\odot\LR{bx^T} \\
\LR{a\odot b}^T\LR{x\odot y}
 &= a^T\LR{b\odot x\odot y}
  = {\tt1}^T\LR{a\odot b\odot x\odot y} \\
}$$
But alas, no rule when all of the variable are dense matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the distributive rule for Hadamard-Matrix products. But for the first part maybe I was not clear enough while I was trying to leave the question the more possibly open. I will consider the case $B_2 \equiv B$. Can I solve, for $B_u$ the equation $$B_u x = B(x \circ p - p)$$, or alternatively $B_u x = B(Px - p)$? Because I cannot use the Penrose pseudo-inverse since due to $m>1$ the inverse is left-multiplicative, and I cannot use the $x^T x$ "vector trick" because it is as well left-multiplicative. 

Hope I was more clear. Thanks for the interest

Comment: @Eventine That's just a linear equation. The general solution can be written using
the pseudoinverse $x^+=\left(\frac{x^T}{x^Tx}\right),\,$
the diagonal matrix $P={\rm Diag}(p),\,$
the all-ones vector ${\tt1},\,$
and an arbitrary matrix $C$ as
$$\eqalign{
B_u &= BP(x-{\tt1})x^+ + C(I-xx^+) \\
}$$ $C=0$ yields the least norm, but other choices could be made in order to satisfy a constraint, for example.

Comment: Ok, here is when math becomes magic for me :D . 
Thanks for the answer